# How do i make one form in a word document open multiple other documents and fill out identicall headers in word / excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-2003

I want the user to open one document that prompts for a bunch of header information, then once the user presses a button, it opens other selected word docs and excel spreadsheets (if possible) then saves and closes them.

Comment: prompts for a bunch of header information ? can u elaborate ? you mean list of files or what

Comment: no i just mean the user types in their name and a part name, part number, etc, etc, into a form, then when they click submit it makes the header of the documents have all that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\test.xls")

and then do ActiveWorkbook.Save  and .Close accodingly

note you can work on one workbook at a time